# Logcat error in Android application

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am having trouble with logcat error. All the classes are error free and also added the classes in the manifest.xml file. When i run my app, after the splash screen the app crashes. I don't know what's the problem. Giving the logcat error.

08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Process: com.example.takeit, PID: 1156
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.takeit/com.example.takeit.MainActivity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.takeit.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:20)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     ... 11 more
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     ... 23 more
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.View.(View.java:3554)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.View.(View.java:3484)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:464)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:236)
08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     ... 26 more

No the app runs. But when i click the register button to save the username and password and go to the menu page then it crashes.

08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): Process: com.example.takeit, PID: 1113
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.example.takeit.SignUP$1.onClick(SignUP.java:46)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-13 15:09:37.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

SignUp.java

```
             public class SignUP extends Activity 
                   {


        EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
        Button btnCreateAccount;

        DataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.reg);

                // get Instance  of Database Adapter
                loginDataBaseAdapter=new DataBaseAdapter(this);
                loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

                // Get Refferences of Views
                editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);


                btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);


                btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String 
        confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        // check if any of the fields are vaccant

               if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field 
              Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not          
            Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                // Save the Data in Database
                                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account 
               Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                  Intent menu=new 
               Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu.class);
                              startActivity(menu);
                        }


                    }
                });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();

            loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
        }

     }
```

Comment: We're likely going to need to see some code.

Comment: Now the app runs. but when i am trying to go from signup form to menu form the app crashes.

LOGCAT error:

Answer (score 1):

This is the error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 08-11 19:06:12.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 08-11 19:06:12.073:
```

you have very big images in your app, check the official [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).